# How to write Bash Script output to chef-client run

Tags: chef-infra, knife

When performing a `knife node bootstrap`, I add a runlist and execute that runlist on that node.

I'd like that execution to have debug logging.

I've [read the docs](https://docs.chef.io/debug.html) here about `-l debug` and `-V` and `-VV`

Comment: Which execution do you mean? Of programs that you are executing or the debug output of chef-client? I mean.. what does the "Bash Script" in your title mean in that regard?

Comment: @StephenKing in the cookbook that I run, I've got a shell block. I would like the output of that block to be displayed in the chef-client logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're passing a specific verbosity level to knife, it [will pass the debug flag to chef client](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/knife/core/bootstrap_context.rb#L130) on a bootstrap. Looking at knife's docs, there's:

> -V, --verbose: More verbose output. Use twice for max verbosity.

Have you tried passing -VV to `knife bootstrap`? It [should make verbosity = 2](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/d8172e646d9fbf43e57bca5e20d0ac352ba9a66a/lib/chef/application/knife.rb#L36-L42), which should trigger passing the debug flag to chef-client during a bootstrap.

For what it's worth, Chef also [copies the verbosity setting](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/mixin/shell_out.rb#L24-L27) into Mixlib::CLI's settings. Thus, when you use a bash or execute resource, you should see the output of your bash script within the debug output.

Hope this helps!